# Jacobian of a smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$   a   subvariety  of  dimension $k$.  How   can  I   define  the  Jacobian  of   a  smooth   map $\phi :\mathbb{R}^t \rightarrow M$  where $t \leq k$?.   It   is   useful  to   know  that  there   exist   a  inner   product  on  the tangent   space   on  every  point  of $M$ ?

Comment: You have to define the Jacobian up to a chart at a point.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: It is like defining the Jacobian of $f:R^n\rightarrow R^m$.